# Calling a "base-class" method from an extended object

Tags: ember.js

Let's say I have this:

```
App.ControllerMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    setupController : function (entry) {
        ...
    }
});

App.BaseEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(App.ControllerMixin, {
    startEditing: function () {
        ...
        this.setupController(entry);
    },

});

App.ServicesEditController = App.BaseEditController.extend(App.ServicesMixin, {
    setupController : function (entry) {
    }
});
```

How can I call `ControllerMixin.setupController` from `ServicesEditController.setupController`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call methods from super classes with `this._super()`. It is generally a good idea to add this call to each method you are overriding.

```
App.ServicesEditController = App.BaseEditController.extend(App.ServicesMixin, {
    setupController : function (entry) {
      this._super(entry);
    }
});
```

Extending on my advise to add this call each overridden method, this is an example of a Mixin for a View. If your Mixin overrides didInsertElement, you should always add a call to `this._super()`. **This ensures that "all" didInsertElement implementations get called, if multiple Mixins are applied.**

```
App.SomeViewMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
  didInsertElement : function(){
    this._super();
    // ... perform your logic
  }
});
```

Comment: Let me get this straight: do you mean that `this._super(entry)` called from *within*  `setupController` will automatically call the method `setupController` on the super class? That means, `_super` calls the method named as the method from where it is invoked? Magic! :)

Comment: If you override a Mixin method in a controller, this._super() doesn't seem to call the Mixin method. How can I do that?